# Grabbing Parameters From the Salesforce URL using a standard page custom button

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-button

im trying to create a Back button on a standard page which will take the user back to a custom visual force page with multiple parameters in the URL, i have brought through the two values i require into the standard page however im struggling to access them.

i first tried: `/apex/ProductOrderManip?ProductOrderId={!ProductOrder__c.Id}&ProductOrderId={!Project__c.Id}"`

which came back with blank values when clicking on the button..
ive just tried something similar to this but struggled to get it to work correctly

```
    function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}

ProductOrderID=a1kg0000000TFiTAAW&ProjectID=a0Db00000051nRrEAI
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [`URLFOR`](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#URLFOR) function that creates a URL  depending on given parameters. Something like this:

```
window.location = "{!URLFOR($Page.ProductOrderManip), null, [ProductOrderId = ProductOrder__c.Id, ProductOrderId = Project__c.Id]}";
```

If you want to grab any URL parameter from the page URL use a global variable [`CurrentPage`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_currentpage.htm):

```
{!$CurrentPage.parameters.someURLparameter}
```

Comment: says theres a missing '}' ?

Answer (score 0):

found out a way of doing this:

```
 function getUrlParameters(parameter, staticURL, decode){

   var currLocation = (staticURL.length)? staticURL : window.location.search,
       parArr = currLocation.split("?")[1].split("&"),
       returnBool = true;

   for(var i = 0; i < parArr.length; i++){
        parr = parArr[i].split("=");
        if(parr[0] == parameter){
            return (decode) ? decodeURIComponent(parr[1]) : parr[1];
            returnBool = true;
        }else{
            returnBool = false;            
        }
   }

   if(!returnBool) return false;  
}
ProductOrderID = getUrlParameters ("ProductOrderID", false, false);
ProjectID = getUrlParameters("ProjectID", false, false);
window.location.assign('/apex/ProductOrderManip?ProductOrderID='+ProductOrderID+'&ProjectID='+ProjectID+'');
```